# Option pricing and GARCH resources

Tags: options, garch, resource

Can anyone suggest resources for option pricing using GARCH models? Although I have a fairly good knowledge of GARCH models, for some reason I cannot seem to be able to follow Duan's paper and how to replicate it with R. Other papers look even more advance, but first I try to understand how GARCH model is fitted to options pricing.